Continuous complex function on open set has locally a primitive?
Today I was studying a book on complex analysis, and there was a theorem which was stating that a continuous function $ f $ defined on an open and arcwise connected set $D$ has a primitive if and only if the integral along any closed contour in $D$ vanishes. While I was reading its proof, I came up to the idea that maybe every continuous function defined on an open and arcwise connected set $D$ might also possess a primitive , but only locally,that is for every $z_0 \in D$, there is an open neighbourhood $B_r(z_0)$ such that $f$ restricted there has a primitive. To prove it, I just imitated the proof of the theorem, where the author defined the possible primitive to be $$ F(z)=\int_{z^*}^z f(ζ) dζ $$ for $z^*$ being some point on the open set $D$ and the integral is taken along the straight line segment joining $z^*$ and $z$(this line belongs to the open neighbourhood we restrict ourselves). Here, to prove that it is locally a primitive, we fix a point $ w\in D$ and then, since $D$ is open, we can take $\epsilon>0$ s.that $B_{\epsilon}(w)\subset D $ and then fix a random point $z^* \in B_{\epsilon}(w)$. To prove that $F'(z)=f(z)$ for every $z \in B_{\epsilon}(w)$ it seems to me clear that we can just apply the  same arguments the author uses on the theorem, and deduce that $F$ is indeed a primitive (the whole line segment from $z^*$ to $z$ belongs of course to the open disc centerd at $w$). But then we get automatically that $f$ is holomorphic also, since it equals locally to $F'$. Where am I doing the mistake here?

You could start with any continuous function which is not holomorphic (for example $f(z) = |z|$) and then see where your argument fails.

@Martin R Yes, I know, it does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations, but I cannot see where there is wrong in my argument. Since locally, f admits a primitive, which I defined it using the integral, why can't f be holomorphic ?

Let $f$ be continuous in an open and connected set $D \subset \Bbb C$ and try to find a local primitive in the neighborhood of a point $z^* \in D$. To simplify the notation I'll assume that $z^* = 0 \in D$. It is correct that we can define the function
$$
 F(z) = \int_{[0, z]} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta
$$
in a disk $B_r(0) \subset D$, where the integral is taken along the straight line segment from $0$ to $z$, i.e.
$$
 F(z) = z \int_0^1 f(tz) \, dt \, .
$$
In order to show that $F$ is differentiable (with $F'(z) = f(z)$) we need to compute $F(w) - F(z)$ for two points $z, w \in B_r(0)$. If the integral of $f$ along any contour in $D$ vanishes then one can write
$$ \tag{$*$}
  \int_{[0, w]} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta - \int_{[0, z]} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta = \int_{[z, w]} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta
$$
and conclude that
$$
 F(w) - F(z) = \int_{[z, w]} f(\zeta) \, d\zeta = (w-z) \int_0^1 f(z + t(w-z)) \, dt \, .
$$
But $(*)$ may not hold if the integral is not path independent, and that is why your approach does not work.
